# How to rewrite urls in apache with parameters generated on th fly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I didn't quite understand how to RewriteRule in apache. I have the particular url:  http://asdf01:9999/TYPE=MSG&PEOPLE=alpha&MS=beta

alpha is the person to send the message to and beta is the message itself. How do I write the rule in .htaccess file?

```
RewriteRule ^msgSend(.*) http://asdf01:9999/TYPE=MSG&PEOPLE=alpha&MS=beta$1 [P]
```

Please can you help me out

Comment: the values "alpha" and "beta" are generated in the program and then the http call is made. (using AngularJS $http)

Comment: What is the full `/msgSend` URL that you're trying to rewrite?